# Multi-tenancy with SQL/WCF/Silverlight

Tags: sql, sql-server, wcf, silverlight, saas

We're building a Silverlight application which will be offered as SaaS. The end product is a Silverlight client that connects to a WCF service. As the number of clients is potentially large, updating needs to be easy, preferably so that all instances can be updated in one go.

Not having implemented multi tenancy before, I'm looking for opinions on how to achieve

- Easy upgrades
- Data security
- Scalability

Three different models to consider are listed on [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479086.aspx)

1. Separate databases. This is not easy to maintain as all schema changes will have to be applied to each customer's database individually. Are there other drawbacks? A pro is data separation and security. This also allows for slight modifications per customer (which might be more hassle than it's worth!)
2. Shared Database, Separate Schemas. A TenantID column is added to each table. Ensuring that each customer gets the correct data is potentially dangerous. Easy to maintain and scales well (?).
3. Shared Database, Separate Schemas. Similar to the first model, but each customer has its own set of tables in the database. Hard to restore backups for a single customer. Maintainability otherwise similar to model 1 (?).

Any recommendations on articles on the subject? Has anybody explored something similar with a Silverlight SaaS app? What do I need to consider on the client side?

Comment: You also need to really think about customization. It might be a lot bigger issue than you think. It is much easier with the first method. You can do it with complicated metadata stores with the other options but this is something to think about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends on the type of application and scale of data. Each one has downfalls.

1a) Separate databases + single instance of WCF/client. Keeping everything in sync will be a challenge. How do you upgrade X number of DB servers at the same time, what if one fails and is now out of sync and not compatible with the client/WCF layer?

1b) "Silos", separate DB/WCF/Client for each customer. You don't have the sync issue but you do have the overhead of managing many different instances of each layer. Also you will have to look at SQL licensing, I can't remember if separate instances of SQL are licensed separately ($$$). Even if you can install as many instances as you want, the overhead of multiple instances will not be trivial after a certain point.

3) Basically same issues as 1a/b except for licensing.

2) Best upgrade/management scenario. You are right that maintaining data isolation is a huge concern (1a technically shares this issue at a higher level). The other issue is if your application is data intensive you have to worry about data scalability. For example if every customer is expected to have tens/hundreds millions rows of data. Then you will start to run into issues and query performance for individual customers due to total customer base volumes. Clients are more forgiving for slowdowns caused by their own data volume. Being told its slow because the other 99 clients data is large is generally a no-go.

Unless you know for a fact you will be dealing with huge data volumes from the start I would probably go with #2 for now, and begin looking at clustering or moving to 1a/b setup if needed in the future.

Answer (score 1):

We also have a SaaS product and we use solution #2 (Shared DB/Shared Schema with TenandId). Some things to consider for Share DB / Same schema for all:

1. As mention above, high volume of data for one tenant may affect performance of the other tenants if you're not careful; for starters index your tables properly/carefully and never ever do queries that force a table scan. Monitor query performance and at least plan/design to be able to partition your DB later on based some criteria that makes sense for your domain.
2. Data separation is very very important, you don't want to end up showing a piece of data to some tenant that belongs to other tenant. every query must have a WHERE TenandId = ... in it and you should be able to verify/enforce this during dev.
3. Extensibility of the schema is something that solutions 1 and 3 may give you, but you can go around it by designing a way to extend the fields that are associated with the documents/tables in your domain that make sense (ie. Metadata for tables as the msdn article mentions)

Answer (score 1):

What about solutions that provide an out of the box architecture like Apprenda's SaaSGrid? They let you make database decisions at deploy and maintenance time and not at design time. It seems they actively transform and manage the data layer, as well as provide an upgrade engine.

Answer (score 1):

I've similar case, but my solution is take both advantage.

Where data and how data being placed is the question from tenant. Being a tenant of course I don't want my data to be shared, I want my data isolated, secure and I can get at anytime I want.

Certain data it possibly share eg: company list. So database should be global and tenant database, just make sure to locked in operation tenant database schema, and procedure to update all tenant database at once.

Anyway SaaS model everything delivered as server / web service, so no matter where the database should come to client as service, then only render by client GUI.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Existing answers are good. You should look deeply into the issue of upgrading and managing multiple databases. Without knowing the specific app, it might turn out easier to have multiple databases and not have to pay the extra cost of tracking the TenantID. This might not end up being the right decision, but you should certainly be wary of the dev cost of data sharing.